# Nginx-gridfs compiling #error must have a 64bit int type in Mac

Tags: nginx, gridfs

running 10.7.2 follow the guide configure than append CFLAGS=-Wno-error to bypass the error, than I got stuck at

```
In file included from /usr/local/src/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/bson.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/src/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/src/nginx-gridfs/ngx_http_gridfs_module.c:43:
/usr/local/src/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/platform.h:50:2: error: #error must have a 64bit int type
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/nginx-gridfs/ngx_http_gridfs_module.o] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem when compiling for Windows. You need to ensure you have a typedef for int64_t and uint64_t.

In order to address I needed to ensure that **MONGO_USE__INT64** was defined.

For Mac you almost certainly have **unistd.h** available - so ensure you define **MONGO_HAVE_UNISTD**